# Get Black Pixels of Writablebitmap using c# WP8.1 Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I have a black & white writable bitmap.

What I would like to do is get all the pixels that have black color and I also want their location in form of coordinates e.g. inside arrays x[] and y[].

How can search pixels in an image in c#?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? For example, why don't just use standart `System.Drawing.Bitmap` class? It has all required to achive your goal.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have reformatted your question slightly please add some of the code you have been working on.

Comment: If it's a `WriteableBitmap`, then in SL you can access each pixel using the `WriteableBitmap.Pixels[]` Property.